# No reliable way enforce DPOP in the browser

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, access-token

DPOP is a specification defines a mechanism to prevent illegal API calls from succeeding only with a stolen access token. [More info here](https://darutk.medium.com/illustrated-dpop-oauth-access-token-security-enhancement-801680d761ff).

But it is a challenge to safely store the private/public key pairs needed to enforce DPOP in the browser. Browser storage options are:

- LocalStorage/SessionSession storage

  - susceptible to XSS attacks if keys are stored in plain text
  - cannot store CryptoKey object which prevents extraction of private keys (LocalStorage only accepts strings)
- IndexedDB

  - great option because it can store a CryptoKey object which safely houses private keys,
  - **Not fully support by all main browsers** (e.g. not support by Firefox/Edge incognito modes, WebView, Safari (iOS 14.8 and prior), Webworkers, etc.)

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

There are perhaps two big requirements here:

- Preventing stolen access tokens being exploited
- Preventing XSS vulnerabilities that can access data

**BROWSER BASED APPS**

The [OAuth best practices for browser based apps](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-10.html) are mostly focused on the second requirement.

DPoP can solve the first requirement but any mechanism to store the DPoP private key in the browser can be abused by XSS, and secrets etc revealed by browser tools. See also [this video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html), which mentions DPoP in its discussion.

A backend for frontend and an application cookie layer is therefore the most mainstream solution. This also remains imperfect in the face of XSS. But stakeholders will perceive a cookie secured app, with threats and mitigations better understood, to be more secure than one using tokens + DPoP in Javascript.

**MOBILE APPS**

DPoP is a better choice in mobile apps, since devices can store keys securely, and injecting script into built binaries is not usually a concern. The attestation support in modern apps can potentially also be used to prove an app's identity, before the authorization server trusts a DPoP token from the client.

Comment: Wouldn’t storing a private key as a CryptoKey stored in IndexedDB with a property of {extractable:false}, prevent XSS attacks entirely?

Comment: If `extractable` is set to `false`, the private key can never be accessed or exported. The CryptoKey object that references/points to the privateKey exposes methods to verify, encrypt, decrypt, and sign data. Is this safe enough?

Comment: On another note, can XSS access this CryptoKey object  (not the actual “private key”, but the object that references it) which is stored in IndexedDB and use it in malicious ways? @Gary Archer

Comment: Yes - that's the concern - malicious code can do anything your code can do, and abuse the CryptoKey object, to act like it has ownership of the private key.